# Is it ok to run multiple PHP cURL scripts via windows command line?

Tags: php, curl, command-line, simple-html-dom

Lets say just **5** different `cURL` Scripts each running on a different `cmd window` at the same time on the same machine. Will that be ok? Will it act the same as running different tabs on a browser?

I would also like to add that some of the scripts have `PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser` in them. Would that change anything?

All thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Comment: this could lead to "you not having basic knowledge" type of closure situation

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can definitely do that. From your code perspective, it is the same as having 5 different users load the site at once. Same from the server perspective. In fact, this is a pretty simplistic way to test simulated load on a page and see how it handles it. Definitely not the best way by far, but quick and dirty.

Just be careful when generating these 5 scripts that you don't end up in a runaway situation where those 5 have not completely finished and exited before you run more. You could quickly overload your own server/site if you end up with dozens or even hundreds of scripts running.

Also be aware that if you're doing heavy processing in those scripts, you may hit PHP/MySQL/Apache timeouts, so keep an eye on that.

Make sure these calls are also thoroughly protected from the public too, or someone else will send thousands of calls to it, also crashing your site.

If you need to do heavy processing it's usually best to do it with a command line PHP script triggered by a cron job. This gives you much more control and security.